# Session does not set in thread

Tags: php, multithreading, session

1. I'm setting session in run method of thread class but i don't access to session from out.
2. And i create file by fopen in run method but the file also doesn't create.

for example, I'm using by the following codes:

```
session_start();
class Async extends Thread 
{
    public function run() 
    {
        $fp = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, '1');
        fclose($fp);    
        $_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
    }
}

foreach ($tests as $test)
{
    $workers[$i] = new Async();
    $workers[$i]->start();
}
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

Comment: You have a typo when you set the session value here ==> $_SEESSION['test'] = 'test';  notice that it has two EE.

Comment: that's an example code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't have several threads per session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007504/cant-have-several-threads-per-session)

Comment: @RiggsFolly not the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update a SESSION or any other variable by multiple threads is not safe !!
What do you want to do is dangerous: you can easily lose data, because your session's update function is not synchronized between different threads
The solution is to update your code like this :

```
<?php   
session_start();
class Async extends Thread 
{
    private $_session = NULL;
    public function __construct($session) 
    {
        $this->_session = $session;
    }
    public function run() 
    {
        // imagine if N threads want to open the same file with 'write' mode ?
        $fp = fopen(Thread::getCurrentThreadId() . '_test.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, '1');
        fclose($fp);    
        $this->_session['test'] = 'test';
    }
    public function getSession() 
    {
        return $this->_session;
    }
}

foreach ($tests as $test)
{
    $workers[$i] = new Async($_SESSION);
    $workers[$i]->start();
    // to synchronize thread operations : wait until the launched thread has terminated
    $workers[$i]->join();
    $_SESSION = $workers[$i]->getSession();
}
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

Notes :

- While i'm doing some tests i have found an issue when i try to update an array in thread, so i've opened a new question in SO http://stackoverflow.com/q/32476271/4098311
- I'm not very sure that `$_SESSION` is visible inside a thread, so i've passed it as an argument to the constructor

Comment: there is a problem. thread is very slow when the session is started.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities.

1) run() function is not called due to some error.

2) As you said that fopen is not create a file, So it it possible that due to some error file does not create and code execution is stop before $_SESSION['test'] define.

Comment: and how you consider this as a response ? please move it as a comment